# Windows feature to prevent limited account from login when admin logon is switched off

Tags: windows-xp, login, user

I am using Windows XP SP2, I have two user accounts (admin and limited), So I wish there could any windows feature when I login as admin and switch user (I mean lock screen), then limited user can't login, is there any way in MS windows (any version)?

Comment: Can't you just disable fast user switching?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am sorry I am unaware about it, how to disable it?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/). "Switch user" won't be available anymore, you'll have to use "Lock screen" instead.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thank you very much, please post this as answer I am accepting it. Thanks Again :)

Comment: If the reason for this is that the users are two separate people, and one wants to prevent the other one from using the PC, it will not work.  The limited user can pull out the power cable, plug it in again, boot, and log in as the limited user.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer LOL very true, but mine is another case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(moving from the comments)*

What you are looking for is disabling fast user switching; this will disable the "switch user" functionality, and you'll have to use "lock screen instead".

As for how to disable it, have a look e.g. [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/), it covers all the latest versions of Windows since Windows XP.

Comment: You are welcome, although this question was a better fit for SuperUser.com. :)

Comment: Oh I see, I never used it before.